# Python JSON data selection

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to extract some info of restaurants from a json data set, here are 2 samples, one a restaurant and one not

```
{"business_id": "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA", "full_address": "4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018", "hours": {"Tuesday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Friday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Monday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Wednesday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}, "Thursday": {"close": "17:00", "open": "08:00"}}, "open": true, "categories": ["Doctors", "Health & Medical"], "city": "Phoenix", "review_count": 9, "name": "Eric Goldberg, MD", "neighborhoods": [], "longitude": -111.98375799999999, "state": "AZ", "stars": 3.5, "latitude": 33.499313000000001, "attributes": {"By Appointment Only": true}, "type": "business"}
{"business_id": "mVHrayjG3uZ_RLHkLj-AMg", "full_address": "414 Hawkins Ave\nBraddock, PA 15104", "hours": {"Tuesday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Friday": {"close": "20:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Saturday": {"close": "16:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Thursday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}, "Wednesday": {"close": "19:00", "open": "10:00"}}, "open": true, "categories": ["Bars", "American (New)", "Nightlife", "Lounges", "Restaurants"], "city": "Braddock", "review_count": 11, "name": "Emil's Lounge", "neighborhoods": [], "longitude": -79.866350699999998, "state": "PA", "stars": 4.5, "latitude": 40.408735, "attributes": {"Alcohol": "full_bar", "Noise Level": "average", "Has TV": true, "Attire": "casual", "Ambience": {"romantic": false, "intimate": false, "classy": false, "hipster": false, "divey": false, "touristy": false, "trendy": false, "upscale": false, "casual": false}, "Good for Kids": true, "Price Range": 1, "Good For Dancing": false, "Delivery": false, "Coat Check": false, "Smoking": "no", "Accepts Credit Cards": true, "Take-out": true, "Happy Hour": false, "Outdoor Seating": false, "Takes Reservations": false, "Waiter Service": true, "Wi-Fi": "no", "Caters": true, "Good For": {"dessert": false, "latenight": false, "lunch": false, "dinner": false, "breakfast": false, "brunch": false}, "Parking": {"garage": false, "street": false, "validated": false, "lot": false, "valet": false}, "Music": {"dj": false}, "Good For Groups": true}, "type": "business"}
```

When i run it prints both even though the category "Restaurants" doesn't exist in the first bit of data, can anyone explain why please?

```
for line in f:
    jd = json.loads(line)
    if jd['categories'] == 'Food' or 'Restaurants':
        print (jd['name'], jd['business_id'], jd['latitude'], jd['longitude'])
```

---

Here's the JSON data in a more readable format:

```
{
    "business_id": "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA", 
    "full_address": "4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018", 
    "hours": {
        "Thursday": {
            "close": "17:00", 
            "open": "08:00"
        }, 
        "Tuesday": {
            "close": "17:00", 
            "open": "08:00"
        }, 
        "Friday": {
            "close": "17:00", 
            "open": "08:00"
        }, 
        "Wednesday": {
            "close": "17:00", 
            "open": "08:00"
        }, 
        "Monday": {
            "close": "17:00", 
            "open": "08:00"
        }
    }, 
    "open": true, 
    "categories": [
        "Doctors", 
        "Health & Medical"
    ], 
    "city": "Phoenix", 
    "review_count": 9, 
    "name": "Eric Goldberg, MD", 
    "neighborhoods": [], 
    "longitude": -111.98375799999999, 
    "state": "AZ", 
    "stars": 3.5, 
    "latitude": 33.499313000000001, 
    "attributes": {
        "By Appointment Only": true
    }, 
    "type": "business"
}
{
    "business_id": "mVHrayjG3uZ_RLHkLj-AMg", 
    "full_address": "414 Hawkins Ave\nBraddock, PA 15104", 
    "hours": {
        "Tuesday": {
            "close": "19:00", 
            "open": "10:00"
        }, 
        "Friday": {
            "close": "20:00", 
            "open": "10:00"
        }, 
        "Saturday": {
            "close": "16:00", 
            "open": "10:00"
        }, 
        "Thursday": {
            "close": "19:00", 
            "open": "10:00"
        }, 
        "Wednesday": {
            "close": "19:00", 
            "open": "10:00"
        }
    }, 
    "open": true, 
    "categories": [
        "Bars", 
        "American (New)", 
        "Nightlife", 
        "Lounges", 
        "Restaurants"
    ], 
    "city": "Braddock", 
    "review_count": 11, 
    "name": "Emil's Lounge", 
    "neighborhoods": [], 
    "longitude": -79.866350699999998, 
    "state": "PA", 
    "stars": 4.5, 
    "latitude": 40.408735, 
    "attributes": {
        "Alcohol": "full_bar", 
        "Noise Level": "average", 
        "Music": {
            "dj": false
        }, 
        "Attire": "casual", 
        "Ambience": {
            "touristy": false, 
            "hipster": false, 
            "romantic": false, 
            "divey": false, 
            "intimate": false, 
            "trendy": false, 
            "upscale": false, 
            "classy": false, 
            "casual": false
        }, 
        "Good for Kids": true, 
        "Price Range": 1, 
        "Good For Dancing": false, 
        "Delivery": false, 
        "Coat Check": false, 
        "Smoking": "no", 
        "Accepts Credit Cards": true, 
        "Take-out": true, 
        "Happy Hour": false, 
        "Outdoor Seating": false, 
        "Takes Reservations": false, 
        "Waiter Service": true, 
        "Wi-Fi": "no", 
        "Caters": true, 
        "Good For": {
            "dessert": false, 
            "latenight": false, 
            "lunch": false, 
            "dinner": false, 
            "brunch": false, 
            "breakfast": false
        }, 
        "Parking": {
            "garage": false, 
            "street": false, 
            "validated": false, 
            "lot": false, 
            "valet": false
        }, 
        "Has TV": true, 
        "Good For Groups": true
    }, 
    "type": "business"
}
```

Comment: As bruno desthuilliers & I mentioned in our answers, it's painful reading that JSON data. Next time, _please_ post your data in a more readable form, preferably with irrelevant fields removed, so potential answerers can focus on your actual problem. For the benefit of future readers I'll add a formatted version of the data to this question, created using `json.dumps(jd, indent=4)`, but please check it to make sure I haven't inadvertently introduced any errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
if jd['categories'] == 'Food' or 'Restaurants':
```

is parsed as:

```
if (jd['categories'] == 'Food') or 'Restaurants':
```

Since `'Restaurant'` is a non-empty string, it always have a true value in a boolean context, so your test is really:

```
if (jd['categories'] == 'Food') or True:
```

which is an obvious tautology.

You want:

```
if jd['categories'] == 'Food' or jd['categories'] == 'Restaurants':
```

or more simply:

```
if jd['categories'] in  ('Food', 'Restaurants'):
```

Now in your case (BTW please take time to post a cleaned up, simplified and *formatted* json snippet next time), `jd['categories']` is a list, so you cannot compare it wit a string - well you can but it will always eval to False - nor use the containment test as above, you have to check wether `js['categories']` contains either of `'Food'` or `'Restaurants'`:

```
if 'Food' in jd['categories'] or 'Restaurants' in jd['categories']:
```

Comment: If i use

    if jd['categories'] == 'Food' or jd['categories'] == 'Restaurants':

I get no output

Could it be an issue if their is multiple categories? I need to check if it contains the restaurants category but it can also have others

Comment: @Ali_bean cf my edited answer. Your json snippet wasn't properly formatted so I failed to spot 'categories' was a list.

Comment: thanks a lot and apologies, i will be more careful with formatting next time

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly easy to test this from the data in the OP, but you need to change your test to something like this:

```
#Get category list from current dict
cat = jd['categories']
if 'Food' in cat or 'Restaurants' in cat:
    print(jd['name'], jd['business_id'], jd['latitude'], jd['longitude'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Line # 3 doesn't seems optimized properly

```
for line in f:
    jd = json.loads(line)
    if jd['categories'] in ('Food', 'Restaurants'):
        print (jd['name'], jd['business_id'], jd['latitude'], jd['longitude'])
```

You may also think of encoding or escaping the string coming from json.loads() function as it will be more appropriate to compare the strings that way.

Comment: i was doing it line by line to figure stuff out as its a 1.5gb data set but thanks!

Comment: Could you please also look at pandas lib - pandas.pydata.org.